# Why variable is accessible only in template when passed by onLoad in ng-include?

Tags: angularjs

I am confuse about how angular scope works!!!

I am passing two variable to one template using ng-init and onLoad. Both variable value accessed from template but there is one controller which I have bound to that template. I am thinking why both variable prints its value from template but prints undefined (onLoad varibale) while accessing from controller.

`Fiddle illustrating my problem` [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rDP2t/2/)

What I understand is, when we pass variable using ng-init, it creates that variable inside current scope but what for that variable which is passed by onLoad??

Please tell me how it exactly works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both variables are accessible to the second controller.

However (it looks like) the second controller is created before the `onload` expression is evaluated.  That being said if you'd like to access the scope variable you can do so through a watch (you probably want to be using watches rather than using the initial values of scope variables, anyway - what if your variable is the result of a promise?).

Here is an example that shows you can access the load from the second controller:

http://jsfiddle.net/rDP2t/3/

Answer (score 2):

Because ng-init is evaluated by angular before the page is parsed by the browser. So the controller picks up the first value. The onload happens after this. So setting the value at onload is too late.